# JSON conversion and app compatibility issues

Tags: java, android, json, spring

I'm using Spring to manage communications between my Android client and a Java backend. In particular the class `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` does the job of converting JSON to Java objects back and forth on Android.

My issue is the following: sometimes I need to update the app, which often results in additional fields to be added to some of the classes which build my model, and as a consequence additional fields in the JSON data that travels between the clients and my server. When I do that it would be crucial for the "old" versions of the app to remain compatible with the new, slightly enhanced, object model. In particular, if the server sends to the client a JSON payload with too many fields (compared to what the client "knows"), the client should just ignore those fields without complaining that it cannot create the object properly. Unfortunately this is not the case now, since if the server sends an additional field, say called "country", the client throws the following exception when trying to convert the object:

```
Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "country" (class com.example.MyUser), not marked as ignorable (19 known properties: ...)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [@JsonIgnoreProperties annotation](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.4.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnoreProperties.html)

Comment: cool! This has to be used with the "ignoreUnknown=true" option and it does exactly the job. I thought this kind of annotations only worked for individual variables.

Answer (score -2):

This advice will sound slightly trollish, but its honest advice-  don't use Spring.  Complicated frameworks like that just cause more problems than they're worth unless you want to use them exactly the way the devs envisioned.  They also make your app slow as hell.  You're better off without them, you'll spend more times working around problems like this than they save you.